# jQuery change() not allowing access to id attribute

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

> ```
> $('.groupselect').livequery(function(){
>     $('.groupselect').unbind().change(function(){
>         _this = this;
>         _id = $(_this).attr('id');
>         //alert($(_this).val());
>         alert($(_this).attr('id'));
>     });
> });
> ```

I can take the value from the element, but i cant take the value from the id attribute, it returns blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puffpio almost had the answer.  Here is an updated version:

```
$('.groupselect').live("change", function(){
  _this = this;
  _id = $(_this).attr('id');
  //alert($(_this).val());
  alert($(_this).attr('id'));
});
```

This is assuming you want the id of the select element.  If you wanted the id of an individual option element you could use:

```
$('.groupselect').live("change", function(){
   $selected = $(":selected", this);
   id = $selected.attr("id");
   alert(id);
 });
```

Go here http://jsbin.com/urugo to see the first set of code in action.  If you want to edit the code for the example go here http://jsbin.com/urugo/edit

Comment: No problem.  I was editting the post to include a link and you had already accepted the answer!

Answer (score 0):

what does this give you?

```
$('.groupselect').live(function(){
    _this = this;
    _id = $(_this).attr('id');
    //alert($(_this).val());
    alert($(_this).attr('id'));
});
```

using jQuery's built in live keyword..maybe that will give better results?